# How to debug my OpenGl Issue

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl

I am using OpenGL Core profile on OS X. From my understanding, DebugMessageCallbacks are not support on OS X yet in open GL Versions under 4.3, i am on 4.1. So I have to use the more basic approach of using glGetError.

This is how I log my output:

```
void glCheckError_(const char *p_file, int p_line) {
    GLenum error_code;
    while ((error_code = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        std::string error;
        switch (error_code)
        {
            case GL_INVALID_ENUM:                  error = "INVALID_ENUM"; break;
            case GL_INVALID_VALUE:                 error = "INVALID_VALUE"; break;
            case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:             error = "INVALID_OPERATION"; break;
            case GL_STACK_OVERFLOW:                error = "STACK_OVERFLOW"; break;
            case GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW:               error = "STACK_UNDERFLOW"; break;
            case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:                 error = "OUT_OF_MEMORY"; break;
            case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: error = "INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION"; break;
        }
        std::cout << error << " | " << p_file << " (" << p_line << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And a shortcut macro I use for this:

```
#define glCheckError() glCheckError_(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

My openGL Application compiles, it runs, but nothing is rendering. I have thrown glCheckError() under practically every openGL Call, and I only ever get 1 error, after glfw initializes, and that is:

```
INVALID_ENUM | /Users/ddodds/CLionProjects/salem-gdk/salem/system/GameLoop.cpp (139)
```

Which from my understanding, is just something that simply happens after some initialization, and can be ignored. But, just in case I am wrong about that, this is where this error is happening:

Called before the gameloop even starts iterating, after glfw/glad initialization:

```
void GameLoop::Run()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glCheckError(); // This is the error
```

Without any opengl error as to why my application isn't rendering, what would be my next step in trying to debug the application? What is the best method for solving problems like this. I am fairly new to OpenGl and it's tools.

Comment: In OGL every error matters, don't ignore them.

Comment: Useful on OSX: [apitrace](http://apitrace.github.io/) and [Xcode tools](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debugging_Tools#Xcode_tools)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated by `glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);` or `glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);` as (you stated) the glDebugMessageCallback is not supported on 4.1 - so you cannot enable it. The OpenGL4 reference says that glEnable generate error:

> GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if cap is not one of the values listed
>   previously.

If the rest of the code has no errors, you may want to check if everything was set up (and set up correctly). The OpenGL is state machine like library and it is easy to omit something (glViewport not set, vertex array not enabled, framebuffer is incomplete, uniform with matrix was not set, etc..). However, there are so many possible places of failure that it is hard to give any reliable hint without more code being shown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question was "how do i debug it", "not what is the solution". I did some digging around, and something i found talked about a common issue with not seeing things render in opengl is they may not be within the viewport i was trying to render, which was the issue in my case. The math for my camera was off. If issues like that occur, how can i make them easier to find?